# Select Multiple dropdwon list from database in Laravel

Tags: mysql, html, forms, laravel-5

in my web application i have added multiple data to database from `json_encode` using multiple select options.

in my database column its shown as below.

```
["Agriculture & Food Processing","Automobiles","Banking & Financial Services"]
```

Now i want to retrieve these data to edit and update. my view is like attached image

[image]

My code is like below

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="industry">Intrsting Industry</label>
<select id="industry" name="industry[]" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="">Select Option  </option>
    <option>Agriculture &amp; Food Processing</option>
    <option>Automobiles</option>
    <option>Banking &amp; Financial Services</option>
    <option>BPO / KPO </option>
    <option>Civil &amp; Construction</option>
    <option>Consumer Goods &amp; Durables</option>
    <option>Consulting</option>
    <option>Education</option>
    <option>Engineering</option>
    <option>Ecommerce &amp; Internet</option>
    <option>Events &amp; Entertainment</option>
    <option>Export &amp; Import</option>
    <option>Government &amp; Public Sector</option>
    <option>Healthcare</option>
    <option>Hotel, Travel &amp; Leisure</option>
    <option>Insurance</option>
    <option>IT &amp; Telecom</option>
    <option>Logistics &amp; Transportation</option>
    <option>Manufacturing</option>
    <option>Manpower &amp; Security</option>
    <option>News &amp; Media</option>
    <option>NGO &amp; Non profit</option>
    <option>Pharmaceutical</option>
    <option>Real Estate</option>
    <option>Wholesale &amp; Retail</option>
    <option>Others</option>
  </select>
```

So how can i selected above list from database.

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need to json_encode it manually, laravel has option to [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) any attribute to array/json:

We're assuming your model name is `Item`.

```php
//Model
class Item{
   protected $casts = [
      'industry' => 'array'
   ]
//snap
}
//Controller
class ItemController extends Controller{
   //snap   
   public function update($id,\Request $request){
      $item = Item::findOrFail($item);
      // no need to json_encode! laravel handle this magically!
      $item->industry = $request->industry;
      $item->save();
   }
   //snap
   public function show($id){
      $item = Item::findOrFail($id);
      return view('item.show',compact('item'));
   }
}
```

```
@php
   // just making an array of industry options, so later we will iterate on it.
   $industries = [
      'Agriculture &amp; Food Processing',
      'Automobiles',
      'Banking &amp; Financial Services',
      //list all the industries here
   ];
@endphp
<select id="industry" name="industry[]" class="form-control" multiple>
   <!-- default value -->
    <option value="">Select Option </option>
    @foreach($industries as $industry)
       <!-- if industry found in current item's industry field we add selected to it -->
       <option @if(in_array($industry,$item->industry)) selected @endif>{{$industry}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

Comment: i got error called "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given". in this case i didn't get data from model. I directly get data through DB::table facade.

Comment: aright, see the whole model thing i described is in charge of casting your industry (that is retrieved as string by default) to array. so if you want to use DB facade you need to cast it on your own. use `json_decode` function cast you industry field to array.